# What's wrong with my Code GPA Calc

Tags: java, error-handling, path, syntax-error

The Code for my GPA Calculator was working fine yesterday but now it returns errors:

```
package problemset.leveltwo;

import java.util.*;

public class gpaCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    double mathGPA = 0;
    double historyGPA = 0;
    double englishGPA = 0;
    double scienceGPA = 0;
    double langGPA = 0;

    // A+
    double a = 4.00;

    // A-
    double b = 3.70;

    // B+
    double c = 3.30;

    // B
    double d = 3.00;

    // B-
    double e = 2.70; 

    // C+
    double f = 2.30;

    // C
    double g = 2.00;

    // C-
    double h = 1.70;

    // D+
    double i = 1.30;

    // D
    double j = 1.00;

    // D-
    double k = 0.70;

    // F
    double l = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter Your Math Grade (percentage)");
    int mathGrade = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter Your History Grade (percentage)");
    int historyGrade = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter Your English Grade (percentage)");
    int englishGrade = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter Your Science Grade (percentage)");
    int scienceGrade = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter Your Language Grade (percentage)");
    int langGrade = scanner.nextInt();

    // MATH GRADE

    // Math = A
    if (mathGrade >= 96) {
        System.out.println("Math GPA = " + a);
        mathGPA = 4.00;
        }

    // Math = A-
    if (mathGrade < 96) {
        if (mathGrade >= 90) {
            System.out.println("Math GPA = " + b);
            mathGPA = 3.70;
        }
    }

    // Math B+
    if (mathGrade < 90) {
        if (mathGrade >= 86) {
            System.out.println("Math GPA = " + c);
            mathGPA = 3.30;
        }
    }

    // Math B
    if (mathGrade < 86) {
        if (mathGrade >= 84) {
            System.out.println("Math GPA = " + d);
            mathGPA = 3.00;
        }
    }

    // Math B-
    if (mathGrade < 84) {
        if (mathGrade >= 80) {
            System.out.println("Math GPA = " + e);
            mathGPA = 2.70;
        }
    }

    // Math C+
    if (mathGrade < 80) {
        if (mathGrade >= 76) {
            System.out.println("Math GPA = " + f);
            mathGPA = 2.30;
        }
    }

    // Math C
    if (mathGrade < 76) {
        if (mathGrade >= 73) {
            System.out.println("Math GPA = " + g);
            mathGPA = 2.00;
        }
    }

    // Math C-
    if (mathGrade < 73) {
        if (mathGrade >= 70) {
            System.out.println("Math GPA = " + h);
            mathGPA = 1.70;
        }
    }

    // Math D+
    if (mathGrade < 70) {
        if (mathGrade >= 66) {
            System.out.println("Math GPA = " + i);
            mathGPA = 1.30;
        }
    }

    // Math D
    if (mathGrade < 66) {
        if (mathGrade >= 63) {
            System.out.println("Math GPA = " + j);
            mathGPA = 1.00;
        }
    }

    // Math D-
    if (mathGrade < 63) {
        if (mathGrade >= 50) {
            System.out.println("Math GPA = " + k);
            mathGPA = 0.70;
        }
    }

    // Math F
    if (mathGrade < 50) {
        System.out.println("Math GPA = " + l);
        mathGPA = 0.00;
    }



    // HISTORY GRADE

    // History = A
    if (historyGrade >= 96) {
        System.out.println("History GPA = " + a);
        historyGPA = 4.00;
        }

    // History = A-
    if (historyGrade < 96) {
        if (historyGrade >= 90) {
            System.out.println("History GPA = " + b);
            historyGPA = 3.70;
        }
    }

    // History B+
    if (historyGrade < 90) {
        if (historyGrade >= 86) {
            System.out.println("History GPA = " + c);
            historyGPA = 3.30;
        }
    }

    // History B
    if (historyGrade < 86) {
        if (historyGrade >= 84) {
            System.out.println("History GPA = " + d);
            historyGPA = 3.00;
        }
    }

    // History B-
    if (historyGrade < 84) {
        if (historyGrade >= 80) {
            System.out.println("History GPA = " + e);
            historyGPA = 2.70;
        }
    }

    // History C+
    if (historyGrade < 80) {
        if (historyGrade >= 76) {
            System.out.println("History GPA = " + f);
            historyGPA = 2.30;
        }
    }

    // History C
    if (historyGrade < 76) {
        if (historyGrade >= 73) {
            System.out.println("History GPA = " + g);
            historyGPA = 2.00;
        }
    }

    // History C-
    if (historyGrade < 73) {
        if (historyGrade >= 70) {
            System.out.println("History GPA = " + h);
            historyGPA = 1.70;
        }
    }

    // History D+
    if (historyGrade < 70) {
        if (historyGrade >= 66) {
            System.out.println("History GPA = " + i);
            historyGPA = 1.30;
        }
    }

    // History D
    if (historyGrade < 66) {
        if (historyGrade >= 63) {
            System.out.println("History GPA = " + j);
            historyGPA = 1.00;
        }
    }

    // History D-
    if (historyGrade < 63) {
        if (historyGrade >= 50) {
            System.out.println("History GPA = " + k);
            historyGPA = 0.70;
        }
    }

    // History F
    if (historyGrade < 50) {
        System.out.println("History GPA = " + l);
        historyGPA = 0;
        }


    // ENGLISH GRADE

    // English = A
            if (englishGrade >= 96) {
                System.out.println("English GPA = " + a);
                englishGPA = 4.00;
                }

            // English = A-
            if (englishGrade < 96) {
                if (englishGrade >= 90) {
                    System.out.println("English GPA = " + b);
                    englishGPA = 3.70;
                }
            }

            // English B+
            if (englishGrade < 90) {
                if (englishGrade >= 86) {
                    System.out.println("English GPA = " + c);
                    englishGPA = 3.30;
                }
            }

            // English B
            if (englishGrade < 86) {
                if (englishGrade >= 84) {
                    System.out.println("English GPA = " + d);
                    englishGPA = 3.00;
                }
            }

            // English B-
            if (englishGrade < 84) {
                if (englishGrade >= 80) {
                    System.out.println("English GPA = " + e);
                    englishGPA = 2.70;
                }
            }

            // English C+
            if (englishGrade < 80) {
                if (englishGrade >= 76) {
                    System.out.println("English GPA = " + f);
                    englishGPA = 2.30;
                }
            }

            // English C
            if (englishGrade < 76) {
                if (englishGrade >= 73) {
                    System.out.println("English GPA = " + g);
                    englishGPA = 2.00;
                }
            }

            // English C-
            if (englishGrade < 73) {
                if (englishGrade >= 70) {
                    System.out.println("English GPA = " + h);
                    englishGPA = 1.70;
                }
            }

            // English D+
            if (englishGrade < 70) {
                if (englishGrade >= 66) {
                    System.out.println("English GPA = " + i);
                    englishGPA = 1.30;
                }
            }

            // English D
            if (englishGrade < 66) {
                if (englishGrade >= 63) {
                    System.out.println("English GPA = " + j);
                    englishGPA = 1.00;
                }
            }

            // English D-
            if (englishGrade < 63) {
                if (englishGrade >= 50) {
                    System.out.println("English GPA = " + k);
                    englishGPA = 0.70;
                }
            }

            // English F
            if (englishGrade < 50) {
                System.out.println("English GPA = " + l);
                englishGPA = 0;
                }


            // SCIENCE GRADE

            // Science = A
            if (scienceGrade >= 96) {
                System.out.println("Science GPA = " + a);
                scienceGPA = 4.00;
                }

            // Science = A-
            if (scienceGrade < 96) {
                if (scienceGrade >= 90) {
                    System.out.println("Science GPA = " + b);
                    scienceGPA = 3.70;
                }
            }

            // Science B+
            if (scienceGrade < 90) {
                if (scienceGrade >= 86) {
                    System.out.println("Science GPA = " + c);
                    scienceGPA = 3.30;
                }
            }

            // Science B
            if (scienceGrade < 86) {
                if (scienceGrade >= 84) {
                    System.out.println("Science GPA = " + d);
                    scienceGPA = 3.00;
                }
            }

            // Science B-
            if (scienceGrade < 84) {
                if (scienceGrade >= 80) {
                    System.out.println("Science GPA = " + e);
                    scienceGPA = 2.70;
                }
            }

            // Science C+
            if (scienceGrade < 80) {
                if (scienceGrade >= 76) {
                    System.out.println("Science GPA = " + f);
                    scienceGPA = 2.30;
                }
            }

            // Science C
            if (scienceGrade < 76) {
                if (scienceGrade >= 73) {
                    System.out.println("Science GPA = " + g);
                    scienceGPA = 2.00;
                }
            }

            // Science C-
            if (scienceGrade < 73) {
                if (scienceGrade >= 70) {
                    System.out.println("Science GPA = " + h);
                    scienceGPA = 1.70;
                }
            }

            // Science D+
            if (scienceGrade < 70) {
                if (scienceGrade >= 66) {
                    System.out.println("Science GPA = " + i);
                    scienceGPA = 1.30;
                }
            }

            // Science D
            if (scienceGrade < 66) {
                if (scienceGrade >= 63) {
                    System.out.println("Science GPA = " + j);
                    scienceGPA = 1.00;
                }
            }

            // Science D-
            if (scienceGrade < 63) {
                if (scienceGrade >= 50) {
                    System.out.println("Science GPA = " + k);
                    scienceGPA = 0.70;
                }
            }

            // Science F
            if (scienceGrade < 50) {
                System.out.println("Science GPA = " + l);
                scienceGPA = 0;
                }


            // LANGUAGE GRADE

            // Lang = A
            if (langGrade >= 96) {
                System.out.println("Language GPA = " + a);
                langGPA = 4.00;
                }

            // Lang = A-
            if (langGrade < 96) {
                if (langGrade >= 90) {
                    System.out.println("Language GPA = " + b);
                    langGPA = 3.70;
                }
            }

            // lang B+
            if (langGrade < 90) {
                if (langGrade >= 86) {
                    System.out.println("Language GPA = " + c);
                    langGPA = 3.30;
                }
            }

            // Lang B
            if (langGrade < 86) {
                if (langGrade >= 84) {
                    System.out.println("Language GPA = " + d);
                    langGPA = 3.00;
                }
            }

            // Lang B-
            if (langGrade < 84) {
                if (langGrade >= 80) {
                    System.out.println("Language GPA = " + e);
                    langGPA = 2.70;
                }
            }

            // Lang C+
            if (langGrade < 80) {
                if (langGrade >= 76) {
                    System.out.println("Language GPA = " + f);
                    langGPA = 2.30;
                }
            }

            // Lang C
            if (langGrade < 76) {
                if (langGrade >= 73) {
                    System.out.println("Language GPA = " + g);
                    langGPA = 2.00;
                }
            }

            // Lang C-
            if (langGrade < 73) {
                if (langGrade >= 70) {
                    System.out.println("Language GPA = " + h);
                    langGPA = 1.70;
                }
            }

            // Lang D+
            if (langGrade < 70) {
                if (langGrade >= 66) {
                    System.out.println("Language GPA = " + i);
                    historyGPA = 1.30;
                }
            }

            // Lang D
            if (langGrade < 66) {
                if (langGrade >= 63) {
                    System.out.println("Language GPA = " + j);
                    langGPA = 1.00;
                }
            }

            // Lang D-
            if (langGrade < 63) {
                if (langGrade >= 50) {
                    System.out.println("Language GPA = " + k);
                    langGPA = 0.70;
                }
            }

            // Lang F
            if (langGrade < 50) {
                System.out.println("Language GPA = " + l);
                langGPA = 0;
                }


    //Credits taken = 12-17

    System.out.println("Math Worth (credits):");
    int mathWorth = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("History Worth (credits):");
    int historyWorth = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("English Worth (credits):");
    int englishWorth = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Science Worth (credits):");
    int scienceWorth = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Language Worth (credits):");
    int langWorth = scanner.nextInt();

    double newMath = mathGPA * mathWorth;
    double newHistory = historyGPA * historyWorth;
    double newEnglish = englishGPA * englishWorth;
    double newScience = scienceGPA * scienceWorth;
    double newLang = langGPA * langWorth;

    int creditsTaken = mathWorth + historyWorth + englishWorth + scienceWorth + langWorth;

    double total = (newMath + newHistory + newEnglish + newScience + newLang) / creditsTaken;
    System.out.println("Total GPA = " + total);

    }

}
```

The errors reutrned are :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:             problemset/leveltwo/gpaCalculator
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: problemset.leveltwo.gpaCalculator
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

If anybody could tell me what these errors mean and how to fix them I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like your class is missing on classpath at runtime. What was the package and name of the class? How are you running the program (command line, bat, sh, IDE, ...)?

Comment: @Boris Šuška the package is package problemset.leveltwo; and the name of the class is GPAcalculator

Comment: No, class name is gpaCalculator. Java is case sensitive language. Is the name of your file gpaCalculator.java? Are you running the program this way: right mouse click on the file, point Run as... and then choose Java application? It will run your application inside the eclipse. Did you rename the files or classes from yesterday?